# How to get specific child values from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get only `player1Name` and assign to String `player1Name`. But I get `null` from the below codes, please help!

[image: Firebase data tree:]

Firebase basic settings: 100% working on this part

```
UserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference gameInfoRef = rootRef.child("user").child(UserId).child("gameInfo");
gameKey = "LMr4xql36nPZFvyX5n9";
```

**`ValueEventListener`**:

```
gameInfoRef.child(gameKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        TextView tv_player1Name = findViewById(R.id.tv_player1Name);

        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            Game game = ds.child(gameKey).getValue(Game.class);

            player1Name = ds.child("player1Name").getValue(String.class);
        }
     System.out.println(ds.child(gameKey).getValue() +"  =All Data");
     }
});
```

**`System.out.println`**:

```
09-20 21:38:14.980 4274-4274/viwil.mahjongcal I/System.out: null    All Data
```

This is not working either:

```
player1Name = game.getPlayer1Name()
```

Error for this:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String viwil.mahjongcal.Game.getPlayer2Name()' on a null object reference

When I change this line

```
gameInfoRef.child(gameKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

To

```
gameInfoRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

`System.out.println` will print all the data (including the String that I want) regardless of the `gameKey`, but I want `player1Name` inside my specified `child("gameKey")` , please help.

Comment: @DudeCoder There is not just a typo is also the way the OP gets the data from the database. There is no need for that loop.

Comment: @AlexMamo... True, I just read the question till `gameKey` gets a value assigned... Then I caught the bug and didnt read further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ids that are generated by the `push()` method, start with `-` (minus sign). So to solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
gameKey = "LMr4xql36nPZFvyX5n9";
```

to

```
gameKey = "-LMr4xql36nPZFvyX5n9";
//         ^
```

And when you are using a direct reference to that particular id, there is no need to loop through the `DataSnapshot` object using `getChildren()` method, you can simply get the values from within it. So remove that for loop and use only the following line of code:

```
Game game = dataSnapshot.getValue(Game.class);
Log.d(TAG, game.getPlayer1Name());
```

The result in your logcat will be:

```
testttggg
```

Comment: As trustworthy as always :D Thanks Bro!
Works perfectly after deleting the for loop!
gameKey was my careless mistake while simplifying the code, i actually get it from intent, but you spot the details as well!